# numbers between low and high in the form A*x+B*y if A and B are known

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

How many numbers between two numbers  say $low$ and $high$ can be expressed in the form of

```
              A*x+B*y
```

where the values of A and B are known to us and low and high is also given to us  ? Here all quantities  are integers .

Comment: Are all the numbers integers? Or at least $x$ and $y$? Are they positive?

Comment: I assume all the quantities are integers. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I came across a solution in which A ,B,low ,high all are reduced by dividing by gcd(A,B) and this way they are made relatively prime and all numbers greater than 2*A**B in the new range of low are surely included but i could not understand the solution or the intuition .

Comment: @satya I'm not really sure I understood what you're saying, but note that the low and high bounds need not be divisible by $gcd(A, B)$

Comment: this is the solution that i got :Obviously, any number not divisible by GCD(A, B) can not be represented as A * x + B * d, so we can divide A, B, low and hig by GCD(A, B) and get the same problem with A and B being relatively prime. (Notice that low should be rounded up and high should be rounded down after the division.)

Comment: now, it can be proven that any number greater than or equal to 2 * A * B can be represented as A * x + B * d. Here is a hint for the proof: for every such number N, 
N mod A = (B * d) mod A
N mod B = (A * x) mod B
and since A and B are relatively prime, we can find values for x and d such that 1 ≤ d ≤ A and 1 ≤ x ≤ B that satisfy those two equations.
To find out if the numbers less than 2 * A * B can be represented in the form A * x + B * d, we can use the fact that for every such representation we can reduce x by B and correspondingly increase d by A to get the same sum

Comment: @cronos2 but i could not understand the solution completely .

Comment: By Bezout's identity, given integers $A$ and $B$ there exists integers $x$ and $y$ such that $Ax+By = \gcd(A,B)$ and that this is the smallest integer linear combination of $A$ and $B$. Notice we can express a multiple of $\gcd(A, B)$ (say $k\gcd(A,B)$) as $A(kx)+B(ky) = k\gcd(A,B)$. It's not too difficult to show that it's impossible to write a non-multiple of $\gcd(A,B)$ as a integer linear combination of $A$ and $B$. So it seems you need all the multiples of $\gcd(A,B)$ between $low$ and $high$. I don't see where any of this $2AB$ business comes into play.

Comment: It seems the solution should be $\lfloor \frac{high}{\gcd(A,B)} \rfloor - \lceil \frac{low}{\gcd(A,B)} \rceil +1$ unless I'm misinterpreting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, you can only represent multiples of the gcb of $A, B$. Specifically, let $L \le H$ be the bounds and $d = (A, B)$, then you're looking for $\left|d\Bbb Z \cap [L, H]\right|$.

You may reduce the problem by making $d = 1$, but I don't think it's really necessary. Just note that $\min d\Bbb Z \cap [L, H] = \lceil \frac Ld \rceil d$, and similarly $\max d\Bbb Z \cap [L, H] = \lfloor \frac Hd \rfloor d$, so

$$\left|d\Bbb Z \cap [L, H]\right| = \frac {\lfloor \frac Hd \rfloor d - \lceil \frac Ld \rceil d}{d} + 1 = \lfloor \frac Hd \rfloor - \lceil \frac Ld \rceil + 1$$